# Allow pfSense to route from LAN to WAN devices

Tags: networking, routing, pfsense

New to pfSense.

My pfSense WAN = `192.168.1.50` (DHCP from my home router)

My pfSense LAN = `192.168.55.0/24`

My Cisco switch = 'Default VLAN1 with 192.168.55.254`

I can ping from `192.168.55.0/24` devices to any device at `192.168.1.0/24`.

However, I can only access the `pfSense firewall at 192.168.55.10` from `192.168.1.0/24` but not the devices on `192.168.55.0/24` network.

Here is the simple topology:
[image]

Laptop can't ping PCs on the LAN but LAN PCs can ping my laptop... What am I missing?

Comment: What is your topology ? UpLink -> home router -> cisco switch -> pfSense ?

Comment: Hi @Marcel, just drew a simple diagram for you. thanks

Comment: In my opinion your pfSense box should be sitting before your home router. That way the pfSense WAN will get the public IP and route everything accordingly, granted that ISP modem is also set to Bridge, to allow routing to be performed by pfSense.

Comment: IMHO you can't call it WAN if it's on the same building... with private IPs.

Comment: I would change it to: ISP modem (bridge) -> pfSense -> cisco switch -> home router

Comment: ah wait, is pfSense a VM running in proxmox ? Is that the reason behind the topology choice ?

Comment: yes, pfSense is running as a VM within Proxmox. That's why this topology suits me the best.

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35716/port-forwarding-on-unavoidable-double-nat-pfsense - disable NAT. Add route on the *outer* network pointing to your pfsense box.

Comment: Hi @vidarlo, I have disabled NAT. where do I add route on the outer network? you mean router? if yes then I already have a static route on the router pointing at my pfsense box. this is the reason I can open pfsense GUI on the laptop (pls look at the diagram)

Comment: Then you have your route. Note that home related questions are off topic on this site.